# CToolTipCtrl with TTF_TRACK Flag won't disappear, SetDelayTime doesn't work?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, user-interface, mfc

I found if set TTF_TRACK flag to CTooltipCtrl, SetDelayTime doesn't work anymore, so the tooltip won't disappear automatically. I want to show the tooltip just below specified control, and expect it to disappear after a few seconds(the time can set with SetDelayTime).
Anybody can help me?

Here is my steps to construct tool tip:

```
1. Add member variable
   CToolTipCtrl m_tooltip;
2. override PreTranslateMessage
   BOOL CPF_GetSetNameDlg::PreTranslateMessage( MSG* pMsg )
{
    switch (pMsg->message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    case WM_MBUTTONUP:
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        m_tooltip.RelayEvent(pMsg);
        break;
    }

    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
3. OnInitialDialog
   BOOL CPF_GetSetNameDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    //tooltip
    EnableToolTips();
    m_tooltip.Create(this , WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_BALLOON);

    m_tooltip.SetDelayTime(TTDT_INITIAL, 0);
    m_tooltip.SetDelayTime(TTDT_AUTOPOP, 30000);
    m_tooltip.SetDelayTime(TTDT_RESHOW, 30000);
    m_tooltip.AddTool(GetDlgItem(IDC_SETNAME), _T(""));
    m_tooltip.SetMaxTipWidth(600); 
}
4. Control to show tool tip
      if(bShow)
{
    m_tooltip.UpdateTipText(_T("Hello, money~"), pWnd);
    CToolInfo       sTinfo;
    m_tooltip.GetToolInfo(sTinfo, pWnd);
    sTinfo.uFlags = TTF_TRACK;
    m_tooltip.SetToolInfo(&sTinfo);

    CRect rect;
    pWnd->GetWindowRect(rect);
    m_tooltip.SendMessage(TTM_TRACKPOSITION, 0, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(rect.left, rect.bottom));
    m_tooltip.SendMessage(TTM_TRACKACTIVATE, TRUE, (LPARAM)&sTinfo );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use tracking tooltips then you are responsible for showing and hiding the tooltip manually. The tooltip timers (like "autopop") are ignored. So you need to create your own timer and hide the tooltip yourself when it fires.